# Changing a string to datetime format in where clause for comparison

Tags: datetime, hive, impala

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
datetime                                 count        
18:28:20.602 UTC DEC 08 2016                1
20:42:32.017 UTC DEC 08 2016                5
15:33:40.691 UTC DEC 08 2016                1
17:11:54.008 UTC DEC 08 2016                3
20:28:57.861 UTC DEC 08 2016                0
.
.
.
.
```

The datetime column is in the string format. I'm having difficulty in converting it to a timestamp.

How do I write a Impala/Hive query so that I get the data between '18:28:00.000 UTC DEC 08 2016' to '18:33:00.000 UTC DEC 08 2016'

Answer (score 0):

With Hive:

```
cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(SHITTY_FORMAT, 'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz MMM dd yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as Timestamp)
```

...will translate your shitty String format into a UNIX timestamp, then into String standard format (in local timezone because that's the Hive convention), then into a Timestamp.
There is no easier way, unfortunately. ***And you may have some edge cases because of the 1h overlap in summer/winter times***.

Source: the [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions), of course...

---

With Impala *(which does not support the `zzz` format modifier)*:

```
cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(SHITTY_FORMAT, ' UTC ', ' '), 'HH:mm:ss.SSS MMM dd yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as Timestamp)
```

...will translate your shitty String format into a UNIX timestamp, ***assuming that all your inputs are in UTC***, then into String standard format (in UTC timezone because that's the Impala convention), then into a Timestamp.